# AWS SDK for Java 2.x: How to configure S3Client with access-key, secret-key and role-arn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I use Spring boot 3 and AWS SDK for Java 2.x
When I try to create S3Client I get an error:

software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.StsException: User: arn:aws:sts::SOME_NUMBER:assumed-role/SOME_TEXT/SOME_TEXT_CloudWatchAgentServerRole is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::SOME_NUMBER:role/SOME_TEXT (Service: Sts, Status Code: 403)

S3Client spring configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class AwsS3Configuration {

  @Bean
  //BTW I don't know if retry configuration is correct.
  AwsClientCustomizer<S3ClientBuilder> s3ClientBuilderAwsClientConfigurer(
      @Value("${cloud.aws.s3.client.retry-policy.max-error-retry}") int maxErrorRetry) {
    return new S3AwsClientClientConfigurer(maxErrorRetry);
  }

  static class S3AwsClientClientConfigurer implements AwsClientCustomizer<S3ClientBuilder> {
    private final int maxErrorRetry;

    public S3AwsClientClientConfigurer(int maxErrorRetry) {
      this.maxErrorRetry = maxErrorRetry;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientOverrideConfiguration overrideConfiguration() {
      return ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
          .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.builder().numRetries(maxErrorRetry).build())
          .build();
    }
  }

  @Bean
  S3Client s3Client(S3ClientBuilder builder, AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {
    return builder
        .region(Region.US_WEST_1)
        .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider(
      @Value("${cloud.aws.s3.role}") String roleArn) {
    final AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest =
        AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
            .roleSessionName("ROLE_SESSION_NAME")
            .roleArn(roleArn)
            .build();

    StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(new StaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicCredentialsProvider()))
            .region(Region.US_WEST_1).build();

    return StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider.builder()
        .stsClient(stsClient)
        .refreshRequest(assumeRoleRequest)
        .build();
  }
}
```

application.yaml
I tried also with `spring:` prefix.

```yaml
cloud:
  aws:
    credentials:
      access-key: ACCESS_KEY
      secret-key: AWS_SECRET_KEY
    s3:
      role: S3_ASSUMED_ROLE_ARN
      bucket:
        name: BUCKET_NAME
      client:
        retry-policy:
          max-error-retry: MAX_ERROR_RETRY
    stack:
      auto: false
      enabled: false
    elasticache:
      enabled: false
    rds:
      enabled: false
    sns:
      enabled: false
    sqs:
      enabled: false
    region:
      static: REGION_NAME
```

Comment: Maybe you're missing the *trust policy* on the IAM role, so that it can be assumed by your IAM user: https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/